# FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN on socket based client/server app

Tags: java, sockets, client

I have FATAL EXCEPTION: MAIN while running the client part of this socket based app:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/

I am using 2 istances of eclipse (with 2 workspaces) and 2 emulators

Here is the relevant logcat:

```
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.clientsend/com.example.clientsend.ClientSend}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at com.example.clientsend.ClientSend.onCreate(ClientSend.java:38)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-22 13:45:59.039: E/AndroidRuntime(2157):     ... 11 more
07-22 13:46:02.770: I/jdwp(2157): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
07-22 13:46:03.380: I/Process(2157): Sending signal. PID: 2157 SIG: 9

any clues?
```

Append code here after AsyncTask try:

```
    package com.example.clientsend;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ClientSend extends Activity {
    private Button invia;
    private TextView txt;
    private Socket socketC;
    private String serverIP = "10.10.45.90";
    private static final int PORTASERVER_REDIRETTA = 5000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_send);
        invia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try{
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
            socketC = new Socket(ipAddress, PORTASERVER_REDIRETTA); 
        }catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new ActionButton().execute();       
    }
    private class ActionButton extends AsyncTask{
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object...objects){
            invia.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    try{
                        // prendere il testo dal componente "Editext" e metterlo in una stringa
                        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        String str = edit.getText().toString();
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketC.getOutputStream())), true);
                        out.println(str);
                        Log.d("Client", "il Client ha inviato il messaggio");
                    }catch(UnknownHostException e1){
                        txt.setText("Error: Host sconosciuto");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(IOException e1){
                        txt.setText("Error: IO");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Exception e1){
                        txt.setText("Error");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You're doing networking on the main thread. Move the networking code to another thread using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). That should be a sufficient wrapper around threading for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have found (and tried) this hint so far searching in Internet, BUT I still get the same error, I think that I haven't understood how to wrap the code with AsyncTask OR I haven't understood how to use methods and istances (relative at my case). here is my implementation:

Comment: @AndreaDiLello Where is your implementation. Please edit your original post as code is hard to read in comments.

Comment: Could you just copy-paste the code and edit it into your original post? And @AndreaDiLello I know this is basic but did you try to `.execute(` it and `getStatus(` later?

Comment: @AndreaDiLello Sorry about not posting code. My reasoning is the classic "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day" vs "teach a man to fish and you feed him for life" reasoning.

Comment: Np! I agree with you, I was just getting late while trying to modify the comment to add the code